# Are the structure of logical expression based on formative constructions like sequences or trees ?

Tags: logic, trees

Recently, I get confused when reading the book *Principles of Mathematical Logic* written by D. Hilbert. How to define the term 'logical expression'?

I just envisage that it might be defined as anyone who occur in a sequence , for whose element, one of the following conditions is satisfied.

A. it is an elementary expression, denoted $X, Y, Z$, ...

B. Constructed by two preceding elements with function notation & (and) $\lor$ (or).

C. constructed by one preceding element with function notation $一$ (negation).

This definition is similar to that of formative construction given by Bourbaki in his *Theory of Sets*, Chapter 1 : Description of formal mathematics.

Another idea is the tree model, the source of leaves just can be elementary expressions, and the tree constructed by &, $\lor$, $一$.

The point is that the two methods can't tell me the precise procedure even when we solve the simple question like : How a general logical expression cab be brought into a certain normal form (conjunction of disjunction ...).

I beg someone could tell me how I find the precise and constructive proof method with manipulation , like computer procedure. I may bewitched by my intelligence, like Wittgenstein said. Could I find some safe proof methods, please recommend some books, I get confused for so long a time.

Comment: I'm confused why would anyone read these books (this and the Bourbaki set theory book)? Is it to try and *learn* these topics? There are newer, better, much cleaner expositions which also take into consideration the decades between Hilbert and us. Is it for historical value, in that case you should probably be proficient with the *current* introductory approaches to logic, and probably somewhat familiar with the history of development of logic and mathematics in the early 20th century.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila - I *partially* disagree with you. You are right in saying that they are not the good "textbooks" to start with, by I like (trying) to understand *how* current "mainstream" science (i.e. *normal* science - ref.T.Kuhn, *The Structure of Scientific Revolutions*) became what is today (and which blind avenues were lost in this process) ... But I confirm again that I will read your future bestselling textbook with great attention.

Comment: @Mauro: If you want to learn about the development of science to what it is *today*, then you should definitely *know* what science is *today*. This way you can "foresee" the past mistakes or the preludes to great revolutions and discoveries. You're only making my point stronger. Learning logic *from* Hilbert (or god forbid, set theory from Bourbaki) is not wise. There are newer, better, cleaner treatments of logic that will help you understand today's jargon while you're at it. Learning about the history of the development of logic and set theory, you should *know* logic and set theory first.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must take into account that David Hilbert's *Principles of Mathematical Logic* is an old book (the first edition was : David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann, *Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik* (1928)).

I think also that Bourbaki's text is not a good point to start with math log.

So said, your idea that the definition of well-formed *logical expression* can be best presented as a formation tree is perfectly sound; see Herbert Enderton, *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (2n ed - 2001) : page 17.

About "the precise procedure : how a general logical expression cab be brought into a certain normal form (conjunction of disjunction)", in propositional logic you can use truth-tables :

> each line of the table which comes out $T$ will yield one of the basic conjunctions of the *disjunctive normal form*, where a basic conjunction is a conjunction with no repetition of a propositional letter (if that letter has $T$ in that line) or of the negation of propositional letters (if that letter has $F$ in that line).

This is an effective procedure (of course, with formulae with more than few propositional letters, the number of rows in the truth-table becomes practically intractable).

Comment: ：Recently I have consulted some books about first-order logic , especially，two books : Herbert Enderton, A Mathematical Introduction to Logic you have suggested; Raymond M smullyan ,first-order logic .I refered to chapters about propositional logic of the two books.I found that the presenation of the former book was very friendly.However,the book written bu Raymond was a little difficult to read but written with rigorous and elegant presenation. the definition of notion formula (or wff) satisfied me but some other questions raised when reading the book of smullyan

Comment: ：Raymond M smullyan, frist-order logic .page9:

Comment: :(when defining the formation tree for formula X ): the points of unorder dyadic tree are occurences of formulas such that the origin point be (occurence of)X..... could we define the term "occurence" ? I tried to understand  the "occurence" like that, formation tree defined as a collection of one unordered dyadic tree together with a mapping from the set S of points in tree into the set of all subformulas of X ,more precisely, "collection" means ordered pair (set of tree,mapping).I do not know whether the understanding will be fine.

Comment: :Raymond M smullyan, frist-order logic .page 10 ......when proving that an interpretation V0 can be extended unique boolean valuation ,I do not know the specific process about "It is easily verified by induction on the degree of X that there exists one and only one way....."  Dear Mauro, how the induction proof works?

Comment: @Russell Thomas - I like Smullyan's book! *Dyadic tree* because each nodes that branches has exactly two successors [page 4 : but we must read "at most", see page 9 : the case of "negation"]. *Occurrence* because a single formula may occur more than one time in the tree. *Unordered*, but then [page 3] we order it, because we have "levels" and each level can be "inspected" from (e.g) left to right [page 4]: this is useful for induction. Finally : YES, you map the subformula on the nodes of the tree, starting from prop letetrs in the leafs and ending with the complete formula in the root.

Comment: @Russell Thomas - the induction on the *degree* of a formula $X$ works this way : *(Basis)* you will start with the propositional letters: they have truth-value, those assigned to them by the assignement $v_0$. *(Induction step)* you go up on the formation tree and *assuming that* the process works for the level $n$ [*induction hypotheses*], you must prove that it works also for the subformula of level $n+1$. But at the new level you have "built up" the formulas with the ingredients of level $n$ using the truth-functional connectives. They "knows nothing" about the formulas ... 1/2

Comment: @Russell Thomas - ... they consider only truth-values : "assigning truth values to the end points in accordance with the interpretation $v_0$, and then working our way up the tree, successively assigning truth values to the junction and simple points, in terms of truth values already assigned to their successors, in accordance with the truth-table rules." The way truth-functional *connectives* are defined assure us that the result will be uniquely determined. 2/2

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA：Sincerely thank you for your help ! I have got the latter one about "the induction on the degree of a formula X...". The following is my interpretation : first, we "construct" function from the set of all subformulas of X into the set of truth values like that----since each subformula of X is of some certain degree which is not greater than degree of X,thus we divide the set of subformulas into finite distinct collections such that each collection collect all subformulas which is of some certain degree.(like divide inhabitants in an apartment according to the storey )

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA: then we define (construct) the function from the collection of degree 0(which are all atomic subformulas) to other collections of greater degree.the detail of the finite consecutive manipulations is:when we face the collection of degree 0 ,we assign them some certain values following the V0,when we face collections of greater degree ,we assign them following B1-B4(since each such subformula reach some other subformula(s) lie in lower degree collection following the unqiue of decomposition).thus easy to verify the function we have constructed is the unqiue assigning we want.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA :For another question about "occurence",I came up one idea last night , the following is my thought: first,the question is that how to find an ordered dyadic tree to correspond for any given formula X .Remark that the general structure of an ordered dyadic tree is (S,L,R, θ) my point is let the elements of the set S be any squence of the form (X1,O,X2,O,....,0,Xn) such that Xi (i not greater than n) come from the set of subformulas of X,O is some certain relation symbol either I or < or >. I have to explain what the relations are---first, we consider the relation of ..1/2

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA: immediate subformula denoted SUB,it is a relation in E ,here E is the set of all formulas. consider an ordered pair (X1,X2)in SUB,we divide the relation SUB into three relations above (I,<,>)preceisely in terms of the form of X1,that is ,when X1 is of the form negation ,let the pair lie in I

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA:when X1 is of some form "b" (we mean conjunction,disjunction,impliation),thus ,when X2 is the left immediate subformula of X1, we let the pair lie in the relation"<",otherwise(means right immediate..),lie in the relation ">".thus,we divide the relation "SUB" into three relation ,easy to proof the three relations are disjoint! second,how could a sequence of that form can be an element of S? that is, whenever (Xi,O,Xi+1)occur in relation O(here O is some certion relation of above three).It really seems complicated,however,after we define the set S ,easy to define the remaining

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA:in the ordered dyadic tree ,that is ,"L","R","θ". we denote a general element of S as e(which is a squence we have defined). L(e)=the lenth of the sequence (do not count any symbol "O")." e1 R e2 "whenever in the form of sequence e2 longer than e1 with some "O,ej" and agree on e1. for"θ",whenever "ei R ej1" and "ei R ej2" occur in relation"R",consider "ej1" and "ej2",each last relation symbol of their squence is precisely one of "<"or ">" ,and they are distinct.thus let the "<" one of  "ej1" and "ej2" be left successor ,otherwise,right successor.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA:At last, we call an element of S with the form  (X1,O,X2,O,....,0,Xn) "a certain occurence of Xn"! dear Mauro,you can try the definition for some simple formula,like[(p^q)⊃(~pv~~q)]v(q⊃~p).Furthermore,I THINK: even it works withou fault,it just a theoretical trick or toy, and i can't find    any practical value . you could verify the tree thus defined fulfill the conditions which the ordered dyadic tree require.AND fuldill the conditions in page 9 .you could try it with some simple example ,as some little trick I want to share with you .incidentally,inspect if it works well.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA: I MISSED ONE POINT: the form (X1,O,X2,O,....,0,Xn) should guarantee that X1 is X itself. and change one point,for Xi in the sequence no need to require it is some subformula of X ,it is can be defined as a general formula, of course ,we can easily verify that any Xi occur in some such sequence must be some subformula of X .

Comment: @RussellThomas - sincerly ... I've found it a little bit "convolute". The idea is: you want to "evaluate" a set (of one or more) formulas. Start with a valuation $v_0$ that assign values to *all* the propositional varaibles (or letters) used (i.e.occurring) in your formulas. Example with one formula $X := (p \land q) \rightarrow p$. We must start with $v_0: \{ p, q \} \rightarrow \{ T, F \}$ such that e.g. $v_0(p)=T$ and $v_0(q)=F$. Then you "go up" the formation tree for $X$: first step (from left) you have the two leaves $p$ and $q$ that are "joined" into $p \land q$. 1/2

Comment: The truth-functional rule for $\land$ says that $T \land F = F$; so you have extended $v_0$ to the sub-formula $p \land q$. Second step (last leaf of the tree form left to right): is $q$, so you have nothing to do; you have already $v_0(q)=F$. Third (and final) step: go up (and reach the root of the tree): you have the left sub-formula evaluated to $F$ and the right one to $F$ also. Use truth-table for $\rightarrow$ and check that $F \rightarrow F = T$; then $v_0(X)=T$. End of process: we have extended the valuation $v_0$ to "cover" all our set of formulas (i.e.to $\{ X \}$). 2/3

Comment: The induction proof is udes to "be sure" that the process ends and that the result is univocal. The ending of the process in ensured by the fact that a formula is a finite string of symbols; so you have a finite tree to "explore". The univocity is assured by truth-functional definition of *connectives*: they know only $T$ and $F$ and nothing more. To check for the sub-formula, you can write them at the nodes of the tree: so the "set" colelction of all the formula ate the nodes (leaves and root included) gives you the complete list of sub-formula. 3/3